# Repost : Query messages theard list

Tags: php, mysql, sugarcrm

Well I'm posting same question again But this time with alternative solution that may work.

I have messages table with following fields.

1) id(pk),from_id(fk),to_id(fk),date_entered,message

My requirement is as follow.

I need to show login users last message with other users.
e.g.

"mahendra" is a login users had communication with "john" lets say 5 message, and with "smith" 3 message.

within these 5 and 3 messages login user(mahendra) could be sender(from_id) or receiver(to_id)

I need to show last communication with login users with each user. something like this

1) mahendra-john     -     This is last message between mahendra and john
2) mahendra-smith    -     This is last message between mahendra and smith

In my last post I couldn't get query to achieve this. So this is what I did.

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE from_id=$_SESSION['userid'] OR to_id=$_SESSION['userid'] ORDER BY date_entered DESC");
```

Now I have all records where login user is either sender or receiver.

now I need to filter last message within other users(john and smith) and mahendra and take it into other array;

Any idea how it could be done ?

Comment: So this question is a repost?

Comment: use AND condition between from_id and to_id and order it DESC as you are doing and take the last value , i guess something like this you are trying to do

Comment: @Kael: I had same question earlier I was trying different way got stuck, post it here, couldn't get solution. Now I tried this way stuck and stuck again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  b.Name Fromname,
        c.name ToName,
        a.date_entered,
        a.Message
FROM
        (
            SELECT  *
            FROM    Messages
            where   (LEAST(from_id, to_id), GREATEST(from_id, to_id), date_entered) IN
                    (
                        SELECT  LEAST(from_id, to_id) as fromID, 
                                GREATEST(from_id, to_id) as toID, 
                                MAX(date_entered) as date_entered
                        FROM    Messages 
                        GROUP   BY fromID, toID
                    )
        ) a
        INNER JOIN UserList b
            ON a.from_id = b.ID 
        INNER JOIN UserList c
            ON a.to_ID = c.ID
WHERE   'Mahendra' IN (b.name, c.Name)
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7ca13/3)

---

**BRIEF EXPLANATION**

Let's break down the full query. The heart of the query is this,

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Messages
where   (LEAST(from_id, to_id), GREATEST(from_id, to_id), date_entered) IN
        (
            SELECT  LEAST(from_id, to_id) as fromID, 
                    GREATEST(from_id, to_id) as toID, 
                    MAX(date_entered) as date_entered
            FROM    Messages 
            GROUP   BY fromID, toID
        )
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7ca13/2)

What the query does is it gets the latest conversation of every user from the `Messages` table with the help of using `LEAST()` and `GREATEST()` function in MySQL. The reason for joining the subquery on table `UserList` (*a table that contain list of usernames*) twice is because there are two columns: `from_id`, `to_id` dependent on this table.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think It will really work for me. I would really appreciate if you explain this query. Cause I have login users id in session and Im not getting where exactly to use it in your query. and please stick with messages table only forget about username.

Comment: so you are interested of using `ID` rather than name. Here it is, [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7ca13/6) , i'll add brief explanation.

Comment: well if I get ID I can fetch users easily. Actually selecting users from table is going to be dynamic depending on other fields in messages table I didnt specified those feilds here to avoid complication.

Comment: basically what values are you going to pass on the query to get the result you want?

Comment: current login user. which will be in session and which could be from_id or to_id

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to check this out, answer in [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/836fa/6)

Here's my query:

```
SET @user_id = 1;

SELECT COUNT(M.Id) AS MessageCount 
    , IF(M.from_id = @user_id, M.to_id, M.from_id) AS CommunicatedWith
    , (SELECT message FROM messages WHERE id = MAX(M.id)) AS LastMessage
    FROM messages AS M
    WHERE M.from_id = @user_id OR M.to_id = @user_id
    GROUP BY CommunicatedWith;
```

This is just the **query** version, if you are using a `stored procedure`, I suggest you replace the session variable `@user_id` with a local one.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but query resulting in all the messages.

Comment: I got what I need KaeL. Thanks for your help.